# Rendering chart from the controller to view

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel chart(laraveldaily)

controller

```
$options = [
            'chart_title' => 'Animals by type',
            'chart_type' => 'pie',
            'report_type' => 'group_by_relationship',
            'model' => 'App\Animal',

            'relationship_name' => 'type', // represents function type() on Transaction model
            'group_by_field' => 'category', // types.category


            'filter_months' => 12, // show only transactions for last 30 days

        ];

        $chart2 = new LaravelChart($options);

        return view('admin.index', compact('users', 'chart2'));
```

In my view I have

```
<div class="row pl-lg-5" style="width: 40%;">
                             <h1>{{ $chart2->options['chart_title'] }}</h1>
                             {!! $chart2->renderHtml() !!}
                             <hr>
                         </div>

@section('scripts')
    {!! $chart2->renderJs() !!}
    {!! $chart2->renderChartJsLibrary() !!}
@endsection
```

I am getting only the title and there is no chart

Comment: you need to use `filter_days` instead of `filter_months`.

Comment: Do you have any console errors related to Javascript?

Comment: It is just bringing a blank page without any data on it

Comment: @Jimmyjbk can you check your relationship working fine?

Comment: It is working perfectly for I have used it in many other places